# Umbraco :: Catching or Extending User Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to catch the login event of Umbraco Users (login in the CMS).

I have tried to extend from `MembersMembershipProvider` and override the `ValidateUser` method. I also changed the web.config to use my class.
When i put a breakpoint in this overrited method it doesnt stop and logsin the user as usual.

```
public class CustomUmbracoMembershipProvider : Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider
{
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return base.ValidateUser(username, password);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hooe you don't mind me asking, but why do you need to catch that event?

Comment: The website i am working on right now,  currently has a fully protected frontend and the umbraco login, and my goal is to login the user in the frontend everytime someone logs in the umbraco. Because i know for a fact that if you have umbraco credentials you are allowed to see the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jannik said, Umbraco uses ASP.NET Identity in the latest couple of versions, so the MembershipProvider is not used to validate and authenticate the user anymore.

So after a couple hours of research, i found a workaround solution:

1º - Create a custom UserManager, and override the method CheckPasswordAsync:

```
public class CustomBackOfficeUserManager : BackOfficeUserManager
{
    public CustomBackOfficeUserManager(
        IUserStore<BackOfficeIdentityUser, int> store,
        IdentityFactoryOptions<BackOfficeUserManager> options,
        MembershipProviderBase membershipProvider) :
        base(store, options, membershipProvider)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the password is valid for the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"/><param name="password"/>
    /// <returns/>
    public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(BackOfficeIdentityUser user, string password)
    {
        //Your implementation

        var result = base.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password).Result;

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

2º - Then in your owin startup, you can use this block of code for your ConfigureUserManagerForUmbracoBackOffice:

```
var appCtx = ApplicationContext;
        app.ConfigureUserManagerForUmbracoBackOffice<BackOfficeUserManager, BackOfficeIdentityUser>(
            appCtx,
            (options, context) =>
            {
                var membershipProvider = MembershipProviderExtensions.GetUsersMembershipProvider().AsUmbracoMembershipProvider();
                var store = new BackOfficeUserStore(
                    appCtx.Services.UserService,
                    appCtx.Services.ExternalLoginService,
                    membershipProvider);
                return new CustomBackOfficeUserManager(store, options, membershipProvider);
            });
```

This solution ill keep using the umbraco UserStore and the base methods of UserManager.

Comment: If someone here has a compilation problem with phase 2, so the solution is to is to add another parameter of entityService.

Comment: `var store = new BackOfficeUserStore(
                             applicationContext.Services.UserService,
                             applicationContext.Services.EntityService,
                             applicationContext.Services.ExternalLoginService,
                             membershipProvider);`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation. This worked for me in Umbraco 7.6.5. I know it's not elegant. It's only a workaround:

```
public class MyCustomEvents: ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        base.ApplicationStarted(umbracoApplication, applicationContext);
        UserService.SavedUser += UserServiceSaved;
    }

    private void UserServiceSaved(IUserService sender, SaveEventArgs<IUser> e)
    {
        foreach(IUser user in e.SavedEntities)
        {
            if (!user.IsNewEntity()) //Is not creating a new user
            {
                IUser alreadyLoggedUser = UmbracoContext.Current.Security.CurrentUser;
                if (alreadyLoggedUser == null) //Is not a user management via backoffice
                {
                    if (user.FailedPasswordAttempts == 0) //Is a successful login?
                    {
                        DateTime justNow = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-5);
                        if (user.LastLoginDate.CompareTo(justNow) >= 0) //Logged in just now?
                        {
                            //Do your stuff
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Umbraco backend uses ASP.NET Identity in the latest couple of versions, it may also be relevant to ask which exact version you are using.

I think ASP.NET Identity has an OnLoggedIn event you could try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onloggedin.aspx

But I'm not 100% sure the link is current.

Comment: I am using Umbraco 7.4.3